# Is special character in Xml attribute value is valid

Tags: xml

I am having xml file with its arttibut value is like New

Is this valid to have xml arttibute value like clean="AT&T".Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode special characters like this: `clean="AT&amp;T"`.

As you can see, the `&` can be represented by `&amp;`.

This is because HTTP does not guarantee data being encoded into a utf format and therefore it is not guaranteed that these can be displayed at the client side.

Here is a table of available special characters and their respective encoded names: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: A partially correct answer. Yes, it should be encoded as '&amp;`. But no, it has nothing to do with HTTP. And the cited list of special characters and entity names is for HTML, not for XML.

Comment: @Michael.. i said http does not guarantee (meaning force) utf encoding if it would there would be no need to encode special characters to XHTML entities.